# how to Show like exist or not in serializer based on request.data in django

Tags: python, django

i have a post model and like model with ForeignKey. in API user will give the user session id . i want to show the user liked a post or not based on the session id in when i list all post . for example . when we open instagram we can as user which post we liked or not in the heart icon .

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  image = models.FileField( upload_to="post/",)

class PostLike(models.Model):
    like = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='post_likes')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likes')
```

views.py

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def post(request):
  if request.data != {}:
     session_id = request.data["session_id"]
     user = Customer.objects.filter(session_id=session_id)
         if user.count() != 0:
             posts = Post.objects.all()
             like_exist = PostLike.objects.filter(user = user).exists()
             serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True,context= 
                           {"like_exist":like_exist)
             return Custom_Response(request, news_serializer.data)
```

serializer.py

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    like_exist = serializers.SerializerMethodField("like_exist_")

    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields  = ["title","image","like_exist"]

    def like_exist_(self,obj):
        is_liked = self.context.get("like_exist")
        return is_liked
```

db

```
post

id title image
1  1st    ""
2  2nd    ""

post_like

id like post_id user_id 
1   1   1       1
2   1   2       1
3   1   1       2
```

if api input session_id 10000 ,it's customer 1
so i want to show like this

API

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "trend post 1",
            "like_exist":true ,
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "trend post 2",
            "like_exist": true,
        }
    ]
```

if it's 20000 , that's customer 2
so response should look like

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "trend post 1",
            "like_exist":true ,
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "trend post 2",
            "like_exist": false,
        }
    ]
```

how get this ? i think maybe it's work with model property . but how . ???

sorry for my poor english,
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need something like this

```
from django.db.models import Count, Exists

@api_view(["POST"])
def post(request):
  if request.data != {}:
     session_id = request.data["session_id"]
     user = Customer.objects.filter(session_id=session_id)
     if user.count() != 0:
         posts = Post.objects.all().annotate(likes=Count('postlike'), i_liked=Exists(PostLike.objects.filter(user=user)))
         serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True)
         return Response(request, serializer.data)
```

And in your serializers.py

```
class PostSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # Annotated fields
    likes = IntegerField()
    i_liked = BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'likes', 'i_liked']
```

Comment: not working bro . btw you mean serializers.IntergerField ?

Comment: What's not working? There are not much modules that supply serializer fields.